# Use $Map or $Unwind or both?

Tags: json, mongodb, dictionary

I want to get an array of results for each of the values within a nested array. The depth of the nest is horrible, it is **objectRawOriginData.Reports.Rows.Rows.Cells**. I didn't want to use this as my example for the forum, hence I've create a more simple one where the nest value for the name is **columns.row.0.value** and the value is **columns.row.1.value**

I've created an example below which might help explain my problem.

What I want to get is an array with the following name value pair:

header 1 : value 1
header 2 : value 2

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("565baae61506995581569437"),
"objectType" : "Report",
    "columns" : [ 
    {
        "rows" : [ 
            {
                "value" : "header 1"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : "value 1"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "rows" : [ 
            {
                "value" : "header 2"
            }, 
            {
                "value" : "value 2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I gave this a go below but, it's not giving me the pair of values. I need not only position 0 value "header 1" but also position 1 value of "value 1".

```
db.testing.aggregate(   
    { $match : { objectType: "Report"}},
    { $project: {_id: 0, columns: 1, rows:1}},
    { $unwind: "$columns" },
    { $unwind: "$columns.rows" },
    { $match: {"columns.rows.value": "header 1"}},
    { $group: {_id: null, columns: { $push: "$columns" }}},
    { $project: {_id: 0,columns: 1}}
    //,{$out : "entity_datapoints"}
)
```

However that just gives me:

```
{
"result" : [ 
    {
        "columns" : [ 
            {
                "rows" : {
                    "value" : "header 1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
 "ok" : 1.0000000000000000
}
```

Thanks, Matt

Comment: I edited your question, so your code can look better.

Comment: no problem my friend.  Just make sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid negative reputations

Comment: I restructured my question and created examples in an attempt to describe what I am trying to achieve. Feel a bit gutted that it has resulted in a negative reputation, I cannot see how to ask what I want any clearer and have read the guide. If I don't know what to ask it is because I don't know even a part of the solution so resorted to explaining the problem I am trying to resolve. How can this result in negative, not a good start, I'm learning and kicked in the teeth before I start :(

Answer (score 0):

Matt, unfortunately you cannot do it as of now. Projecting key names as value of another field is not yet possible in mongoDB using aggregation. According to this [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5947), it is currently "planned but not scheduled".

I think you can achieve similar thing by doing [map reduce](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/).

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I look up map reduce, I see that works where two or more values exist per array set. The problem I have is that I have a value for name in one set within an array and the corresponding value in a different set within the same array. The one thing I do know is that the name is always at position 0 and the value is always at position 1 of the same set. Is there no way of querying the location of a FIND so that you get the path and position numbers and then use that path modified to retrieve a specific element's value? Thanks, Matt

Comment: I think I need to use $slice to get position 0 and then again for position 1, maybe also include $limit and/or $skip. :) Working through some ideas but still walking backwards, thanks